# How do I access public method before it's been declared?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I know it's an oxymoron, but I needed a title. ;-)

Consider this

```
define([], function() {
...
var obj = this.publicMethod(); // This line will break with error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'publicMethod' 
return {publicMethod: function() {...}}
```

How do I access publicMethod?

Or am I structuring it all wrong?

Comment: Try `var obj = publicMethod;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define this function above :

```
define([], function() {
  ...

  function myMethod() {
  ...
  }
  var obj = myMethod(); 
  return {publicMethod: myMethod}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your module to something like this:

```
define( [], function(){

  function publicMethod() {
    // code
  }

  var obj = publicMethod();


  return { 'publicMethod': publicMethod };

});
```